# How to make sure a remote image downloaded to server is actually an image with PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I am building a PHP app which will be distributed to hundreds or thousands of users as a SugarCRM module.  The functionality I am working on allows users to upload images from a remote URL.

StackOverflow has this same functionality, shown in the image at the bottom.

I mention this being on other servers because my upload function needs to be very reliable across many server configurations and web hosts!

To help make it more reliable in fetching and downloading remote images, I have some checks in my `fetch_image($image_url)` function like...

`ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` to see if they allow `file_get_contents()` to use URLs instead of file paths.

I use `function_exists('curl_init')` to see if CURL is installed.

Besides getting the remote image using several methods.  I now also need to ensure that the file returned or built from the remote server is actually a legit image file and not some sort of malicious file!

Most servers at least have `GD image processor` installed so perhaps it could be used somehow on my image to make sure it is an image?

My code so far is below...

Any help appreciated in checking to ensure image is image!

The sockets method seems to actually generate a file saved in the server temp folder.  Other methods just return the string of the image.

```
<?php

class GrabAndSave {

    public $imageName;
    public $imageFolderPath = 'remote-uploads/'; // Folder to Cache Amazon Images in
    public $remote_image_url;
    public $local_image_url;
    public $temp_file  = '';
    public $temp_file_prefix = 'tmp';

    public function __construct(){
        //
    }

    public function fetch_image($image_url) {

        // check if CURL is installed
        if (function_exists('curl_init')){
            return $this->curl_fetch_image($image_url);
        // Check if PHP allows file_get_contents to use URL instead of file paths
        }elseif(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
            return $this->fopen_fetch_image($image_url);
        // Try Sockets
        }else{
            return $this->sockets_fetch_image($image_url);
        }
    }



    public function curl_fetch_image($image_url) {

        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
             //Initialize a new resource for curl
             $ch = curl_init();

             //Set the url the retrieve
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);

             //Return the value instead of outputting to the browser
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

             $image = curl_exec($ch);
             curl_close($ch);

             if ($image) {
                  //Do stuff with the image
                  return $image;
             } else {
                  //Show error message
             }

        }else{
            die('cURL is not enabled on this server.');
        }
    }


    public function fopen_fetch_image($url) {
        $image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $image;
    }


    public function sockets_fetch_image($image_url)
    {
        if($this->temp_file)
        {
            throw new Exception('Resource has been downloaded already.');
        }

        $this->temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $this->temp_file_prefix);

        $srcResource = fopen($image_url, 'r');
        $destResource = fopen($this->temp_file, 'w+');

        stream_copy_to_stream($srcResource, $destResource);

        return $this->temp_file;
    }


    public function save_image($image_filename, $raw_image_string){
            $local_image_file = fopen($this->imageFolderPath . $image_filename, 'w+');
            chmod($this->imageFolderPath . $image_filename, 0755);
            fwrite($local_image_file, $raw_image_string);
            fclose($local_image_file);
    }

}
```

---

**Preview of the StackOverflow image dialog using remote URL image upload...**
[image]

Comment: Any image file or certain types (png, jpg)?

Comment: @lxg the usual png, jpg, gif I would assume

Comment: Ok, then see my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and effective method is using [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize) on the file. A legitimate file will deliver an array of image meta data for many common image file types. (This can, by the way, also be used to enforce additional constraints, such as the image dimensions.)

Keep in mind that even legitimate images may contain malicious code, as various image viewers have exposed security issues with image data streams in the past. It may add a layer of security to internally convert the image before delivering it in order to protect clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- check response headers, especially "Content-Type" header
- check file mime type
- check actual file signature
- try to actually create image resource from the file
- other...

Comment: Content-Type and mime type are basically the same and can easily be forged.

Comment: Sure, but for example "Content-Type" header can be used for check before actually downloading remote file to server. HEAD request can be sent first, and if "Content-Type" header matches image, then check file size by checking "Content-Length" header, and if it looks OK, then send request to download the actual file and continue with other checks/validations after download is finished. For non-forged responses it will help by preventing download of files which are actually not images, or are too big. For example, think about the situation when someone insert link to a 100 MB or few GB file.

Comment: 1. We are the server here, so we cannot “send a request”. 2. Content-Length is also easily manipulated. 3. `max_upload_size` is your friend when you want to limit the upload size.

Comment: If you actually read the title of the question ("How to make sure a **remote image downloaded to server** is actually an image with PHP?"), and the question itself, you will notice that they are giving the user an option to type/insert some image url, and their server will fetch and process remote file. So, as you can see in question source code, on their server they are using `curl`, `file_get_contents` and `sockets` to "__send a request__" to remote url and fetch the file to their server, before processing. So, in this case `max_upload_size` is of no help ;)

Comment: Ok, sorry, you're right about that part. I was irritated by the upload dialog.